# TSQL Insert and delete duplicates improving query performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm using these two queries to insert the data first into the transactions refined table from the transactions dump and then delete the possible duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions_Refined]
    SELECT 
        Client_ID,
        Customer_ID,
        Transaction_ID,
        SUM(try_parse(value_sold AS numeric(18,2))) AS value_sold,
        SUM(try_parse(quantity AS numeric(18,4))) AS quantity,
        subclass,
        article,
        try_parse(Transaction_Date AS Datetime) AS Transaction_Date,
        Store_ID
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Transaction_Dump]
    GROUP BY 
        Client_ID, Customer_ID, Transaction_ID,
        try_parse(Transaction_Date AS Datetime),
        subclass, article, Store_ID ;

WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
       *,
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Client_ID, Customer_ID, Transaction_ID, value_sold, quantity, subclass, article
                         ORDER BY Client_ID, Customer_ID, Transaction_ID, value_sold, quantity, subclass, article) AS [rn]
   FROM 
       [dbo].[Transactions_Refined]
   WHERE 
       Client_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Client_ID]
                     FROM [dbo].[Transaction_Dump]) )
DELETE cte
WHERE [rn] > 1 ;
```

I would like to speed up the process. Any Idea? I'm thinking of using an outer join.

Comment: Is Transaction_Dump a table that you load from some text file? 

Is that the reason why you use TRY_PARSE? 

How many records does it typically contain? 

And how many records does Transactions_Refined contain? 

Is it a cumulative table that you append to and that continually grows?

I see that you use ROW_NUMBER in order to delete duplicate keys, but aren't you losing information in this way?

Comment: Replace `IN DISTINCT` with `EXISTS`

Comment: To: tomislav_t Yes the data comes from a text file and I parse it because I need to convert it into proper formatted data. I'm not using SSIS I'm Using Azure Data Factory. Yes you got it I'm appending the data. No I'm not losing the information that I need.

Comment: `distinct` in subquery doesn't change result but affect performance.

Comment: I don't understand why insert and delete when you can use merge update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code imports data from a text file into Transaction_Dump. The GROUP BY in the first statement takes care of aggregating individual transactions by Client_ID, Customer_ID, Transaction_ID, Transaction_Date, subclass, article, Store_ID and sums value_sold and quantity.

The aggregated records get inserted in Transaction_Refined. We assume this process is repeated periodically so that eventually Transaction_Refined will become very large.

After insertion in Transaction_Refined, some unwanted duplicates occur. These duplicates get removed by the DELETE statement with the CTE. The CTE scopes the DELETE statement, it selects the records from Transaction_Refined with ClientId's that were mentioned in the latest Transaction_Dump.

I suspect there is an error in the code above. The aggregation in the insert takes place among others on StoreId and Transaction_Date. This makes sense.

Strange is that the DELETE code will remove duplicates by not grouping on StoreId and Transaction_Date for the ClientId's that have occurred in the latest Transaction_Dump.

Important question now is whether the ClientId's used are unique per Transaction_Dump file. I would assume this is not true, i.e. one ClientId could have multiple orders on differnt days.

The above DELETE statement would basically lose Transaction_Refined records as it disregards StoreId and Transaction_Date.

There are two ways to solve this:

Option 1: You treat Transaction_Refined as an aggregated table where you keep the transactions aggregated per day. In this case, we could make the DELETE statement and the CTE obsolete by removing the duplicates in the insert.

Option 2: You treat Transaction_Refined as a kind of grand total of transactions per client over all StoreId's and Transaction_Date. If this is the case then the columns StoreId and Transaction_Date should be removed from the Transaction_Refined table and there should be code to INSERT new records or UPDATE existing records as required to keep the aggregation correct.

Next step would be to decide whether you want to go for Option 1 or for Option 2. Once you have that, it should be easy to make very efficient TSQL code to update the Transaction_Refined table.